# MongoDB get sum of fields in last stage of aggregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, group-by, aggregation-framework

I'm using an aggregate to gather some related data. The following is a sample pipeline that joins a Parent Collection to a Children One (Each Parent will have a Child).

I then use a projection to gather some fields from both collections. This includes getting a count of the "number of sodas" a child has.

Ultimately, I'm aiming to get a total of all the sodas that all children have (So basically a summation of the `childSodaCount` field in the projection.

I attempted this by appending a `group` stage at the end of the pipeline. THis does work, however, I lose all the other fields from the projection.

Any insights?

```
[
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'Children', 
      'localField': 'childId', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'CHILDREN'
    }
  } {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$CHILDREN' 
    }
  } {
    '$project': {
      'childSodaCount': {
        '$size': '$CHILDREN.sodas'
      }, '
      'parentName': 1, 
      'parentFoo': 1, 
      'parentBar': 1, 
     
      'childName': {
        '$concat': [
          '$CHILDREN.firstName', ' ', '$CHILDREN.lastName'
        ]
      }, 
    {
    '$group': {
      '_id': null, 
      'TOTAL_CHILD_SODA_COUNT': {
        '$sum': '$childSodaCount'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically `$group` by null will group all documents in a single document, Try `$facet` to separate both result after `$project` stage,

```
{
  $facet: {

    // All documents
    docs: [ { $match: {} } ],

    // Total child soda
    TOTAL_CHILD_SODA_COUNT: [
      {
        $group: {
          _id: null,
          count: {
            $sum: "$childSodaCount"
          }
        }
      }
    ]

  }
}
```

This will result something like,

```
[
  {
    docs: [{}, {}, .. all docs]
    TOTAL_CHILD_SODA_COUNT: [{ _id: null, count: 1 }] // total count
  }
]
```

If you want to get direct count instead of array of object try `$addFields` stage after `$facet` stage,

```
{
  $addFields: {
    TOTAL_CHILD_SODA_COUNT: { $arrayElemAt: ["$TOTAL_CHILD_SODA_COUNT.count", 0] }
  }
}
```

Your final result will be,

```
[
  {
    docs: [{}, {}, .. all docs]
    TOTAL_CHILD_SODA_COUNT: 1 // total count
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Didn't know about facet. Any ideas on the impact on performance this could have while adding it to the last stage of the pipeline?

Comment: it would not but i would suggest to add limit in docs though pagination. if there are lots of document in result.